# Execute alias in cshrc

Tags: linux, shell, alias, csh

I have alias which contain small script. We generally call alias with username argument.
For small enhancement,we need to call from shell script. I have write into shell script but it looks like that it does not work

```
/usr/local/buildpkgs/latest/TclDevKit2.6/bin/tclsh 
      $VDK_PATH/scripts/ves.tcl /bin/csh $vdktmpfile !*;source  
      $vdktmpfile;/bin/rm $vdktmpfile;
      /usr/local/buildpkgs/latest/TclDevKit2.6/bin/tclsh 
      $VDK_PATH/scripts/vep.tcl $vdktmpfile $SHELL "$prompt:q"; 
      source  $vdktmpfile; /bin/rm $vdktmpfile   = sample
```

we generally invoke alias from command line like `sample <username>.`We need to call this alias from cshell scrip similar way  `sample <username>`.
Does anyone help me to figure out this issue.

Note: I never seen such a long alias if anyone provide me detail  it will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the alias specified? If not in .bashrc but in a general shell script, then you will have to inside of your current shell script:
a) first invoke shell script containing the alias then 
b) call alias as you normally do i.e `sample <username>`

Other alternative is you might want to call your shell script like this:

```
. ./<script-name>.sh <args>*
```

as opposed to just

```
./<script-name>.sh <args>*
```

the extra period is to execute script in current shell where alias already defined and not create its own process